# How do you swap the caps lock key  to control key in lxde?

Tags: keyboard, configuration, lxde, shortcut-keys

I know it is easy to this in Gnome, but how can I do it in LXDE?

Answer (score 6):

If you are the only person using the machine then the easiest option is to include the following line in the keyboard section of your XF86Config-4 file.

```
  Option          "XkbOptions"    "ctrl:swapcaps"
```

These ensures that the swap is done automatically whenever X starts.

(Reference: http://www.manicai.net/comp/swap-caps-ctrl.html)